# How to change namespace for default member import javascript

Tags: javascript, import

In learning more about ES6/2015 imports, I've come across a couple of cases where I'd like to change the namespace of the default member in the import scope.

Basically the equivalent of `import {myMember as name} from 'my-module'`, but for the default member. I expected something like `import defaultMember, {defaultMember as name} from 'my-module'`, but that seems not to work.

It seems like this should possible:
[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> It is also possible to use the default syntax with the ones seen above (namespace imports or named imports). In such cases, the default import will have to be declared first...

Comment: The Mozilla Docs don't say that you can import a defaultMember with an alias. Instead just write `yourVar = defaultMember` on the next line after importing the defaultMember

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was resorting to.. unfortunately a little pollution in the namespace.

Comment: I found a solution that worked well. I just did an import/export in another codefile/module that transposed the convention. Then I imported that new convention, and then re-asserted the intended default convention in the global namespace. Worked fine.

Comment: Interesting. Can you write that below (in answer form)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the actual answer, but a solution that I'm using.

For this example, I was using Node-Simple-Schema, and did not want to track imports of it as it is often used across the global scope on the project I'm working on.

The problem is that when `import SimplSchema from "simpl-schema';` is used, then "SimpleSchema" as a convention is not available globally.

So I created a code file "SS2.js" and placed the following in it:

> import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
>
> var SS2 = SimpleSchema;
>
> export {SS2};

Then in the working file, I do a subsequent "chained" import and with the following:

> import {SS2} from './imports/SS2.js';
>
> SimpleSchema = SS2;

This gives me the default module export convention "SimpleSchema" available globally once again.